# Cocos Code IDE unable to find python

Tags: javascript, cocos2d, windows-8, cocos2d-x-js

I am trying to create a new `JavaScript` project on Cocos Code IDE but every time it immediately give me the error message:

> Unable to find python. Please, click the setting button to set the python path, then python 3.0 or later is not supported.

I click the button and I set the path to `C:\Python27` which is the folder of my python installation, and I try again but I get exactly the same error. The version of my python installation is **2.7.8**. I am using **Windows8.1**.

**EDIT:** It occurred to me that there is also another error message:

> ```
> the python's version must be greater than or equal to 2.7.5 and less than 3.0
> ```

But I cannot understand why it does not accept my version(**2.7.8**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that the problem was fixed by using the **32-bit** version of python instead of the **64-bit**.